# Vertx Eventbus not working in Java

Tags: java, vert.x

OS Linux
JDK 1.7.0_67
Vert.x 2.1.5

Just getting started for wiring some of the vertx examples found on github.

Due to the manual want to try out a simple Sender <-> Receiver example, over EventBus. Many hours later, no ping, neither a hello world.

Anyone has an idea, what I'm missing on this simple code:

**Sender.java**

```
import org.vertx.java.platform.Verticle;

public class Sender extends Verticle {

  public void start(){
    vertx.eventBus().send("ping-address", "Hello");
  }
}
```

**Receiver.java**

```
import org.vertx.java.core.Handler;
import org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.Message;
import org.vertx.java.platform.Verticle;

public class Receiver extends Verticle {

  public void start() {
    EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();
    eb.registerHandler("ping-address", new Handler<Message<String>>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(Message<String> message) {
            container.logger().info("Message: "+message.body());
        }
    });

    container.logger().info("PingVerticle started");

  }
}
```

Running both in seperate JVM instances on the same machine, with following CLI command:

```
vertx run Receiver.java
> Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

another console:

```
vertx run Sender.java
> Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you're running the vertices, they won't be able to see each other. They're essentially being started as completely separate processes with clustering disabled (the default). You have to run the vertices in cluster mode in order to get them to locate and communicate with one another. Use the `-cluster` option to enable Hazelcast clustering. You may also want to specify `-host` or `-port`.

If you continue seeing problems with even bus communication after that, enable Hazelcast logging and ensure the two nodes see each other. You may have to alter `cluster.xml` (the Hazelcast configuration) if your network does not support multicast.

Comment: By the way, this is question has been answered numerous times on the [Vert.x Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/vertx)

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day. Didn't understand why this option is not mentioned in the official docs as a must have for using eventbus.

Comment: I know! We'll try to make sure the documentation on clustering is clearer in Vert.x 3. I had this exact same problem when I first tried using it!

Answer (score 2):

Might be helpful for those who is using programmatic way of clustering. 
Please check you have the following values set in your vertx options:

```
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClustered(true)
                .setClusterHost("198.12.12.12")
                .setHAEnabled(true)
                .setHAGroup("dev");

 Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> System.out.println(res.succeeded()));
```