# Vertx: Lots of sent messages arent received in eventbus - why?

Tags: java, sendmessage, vert.x, event-bus

i've programmed two verticles which are resided on different machines and they should communicate with each other with Json-Messages. Lets say the Ip on Machine1 is "192.168.50.45" and ip from Machine2 is "192.168.50.69". Vertx is clustered and verticle on machine1 should send a message, verticle on machine2 should receive the message on machine2.

Now the problem:

Normally each sent message from verticle on machine1 should received by verticle on machine2 , but i seems to be that only a part of the periodically send messages are received. Get it stucked anywhere? Or maybe the receipt is very slow? Could this be? The curious thing is that if I deploy both verticles together on my local machine there is no such problem and everthing does like it should do.

Here is the code from Verticle from machine1:

```
public class Sender extends AbstractVerticle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().addTrustedInterface("192.168.3.69");

        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
        options.setClusterManager(new HazelcastClusterManager(config));
        options.setClusterHost("192.168.3.45");
        options.setClustered(true);

        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
            Vertx vertx = res.result();
            vertx.deployVerticle(new Sender());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        vertx.setPeriodic(1500, id -> {
            vertx.eventBus().send("test", "Buh");
            System.out.println("SEND!");
        });

    }
}
```

Code from machine2:

```
public class Receiver extends AbstractVerticle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().addTrustedInterface("192.168.3.45");

        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
        options.setClusterManager(new HazelcastClusterManager(config));
        options.setClustered(true);
        options.setClusterHost("192.168.3.69");

        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
            Vertx vertx = res.result();
            vertx.deployVerticle(new Receiver());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        MessageConsumer<String> consumer = vertx.eventBus().consumer("test");
        consumer.handler(message -> {
            System.out.println(message.body());
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Although that won't solve your problem, but have you tried looking at the metrics of the eventbus from the two vert.x instances? See http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/java/#_event_bus_metrics Do they tell anything about lost or failed messages? Maybe that could be a first hint.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983863/vertx-eventbus-not-working-in-java

Try to enable hazelcast logging to see if the problem is on that layer (message being put onto the eventbus but never distributed across the cluster).

Comment: Since send is a point to point communication, there is the possibility that you have an invisible cluster participant, which "eats" your message (http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#send-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-). Try to change send to publish and check again if you loose messages. With the hazelcast logging described by DaDaDom you should see the amount of cluster participants.

Comment: Some times ago I wrote a cluster watchdog, perhaps this is useful for you https://github.com/swisspush/vertx-cluster-watchdog